# Parameter estimation of a transformation

Tags: estimation, data-transformation, sample

imagine you have a sample $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ from a random variable $X$, and another sample $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_m$ from a random variable $Y$. You know that $Y = \phi(X)$. For concreteness, say $Y = a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 X^2$. How can you estimate $a_0$, $a_1$ and $a_2$ from the samples?

You don't how $X$ or $Y$ are distributed, and your samples do not come in pairs. In fact, $n \neq m$.

I am stuck trying to solve this. Perhaps it is a well-known problem in the statistics community, but I am unable to find anything about it.

Thanks.

Comment: So to be clear, I don't observe pairs of $X$ and $Y$?  That is to say $Y_1$ is NOT the transformation of $X_1$?  $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are unrelated?

Comment: No, you don't observe them in pairs. The samples are independent.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be constructing a KDE for $Y$ and calculating the likelihood of $\hat Y_i=a_0+a_1X_i+a_2X_i^2$, and then getting maximum likelihood estimate for the parameters $a_0,a_1,a_2$.

**More Explanation**: Since we don't have corresponding pairs in both datasets, one thing we can do is to estimate the PDF of $Y$, by using some approach. KDE ([Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)) is a useful, non-parametric method for doing this. KDE will gives us an estimate of $f_Y(y)$, i.e. $\hat f_Y(y)$.

Then, we can calculate the likelihood of the $X$ data using:
$$L(X|a)=\prod_{i=1}^n \hat f_Y(a_0+a_1x_i+a_2x_i^2)$$

And, find $a_k$ that maximizes this expression. This is mostly a numerical approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @JochiToborochi I've added more details.

Comment: I think the likelihood function of $X$ is $\hat{f}_Y(\phi(x)) / \phi'(x)$, so here $ \hat{f}_Y(\phi(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2)) / (a_1 + 2 a_2 x)$, no ?

Comment: Well, not even, since here $\phi$ is not monotonous... but I think the likelihood of $X$ is more complex than just $\hat{f}_Y(\phi(x))$.

Comment: It seems like a good idea to use KDEs, thanks. I was trying to use quantile functions, but I think I'll go your way.

Comment: @Pohoua if we had two set of samples for $Y$, we could just compare their likelihoods as above. Why not do this using the alleged $y$'s?

Comment: @Gunes: Do you mean that you consider $L(\phi(X) \mid a)$ instead of $L(x \mid a)$ ? 
I yes, I would agree with that if $\phi$ did not depend on the parameter to estimate, but it's not the case. in a scale model for instance $Y = \sigma \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon \sim F$ the likelihood is $L(Y\mid\sigma) = \prod_i f(Y / \sigma) / \sigma$ and not $L(Y\mid\sigma) = \prod_i f(Y / \sigma)$.

Comment: Actually now I realized that we are using the wrong notation for likelihood, i.e. it should be $L(a|..)$. I'll either be badly mistaken or be more rigorous after this discussion :) I think, we should be able to write (for an independent set of samples) $$f_\mathbf{Y}(Y_1,...,Y_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n f_Y(y)$$ and any alleged sample of $Y$'s have some probability mass using this formula. In your example, $f$ seems to be the PDF of $\epsilon$ but I'm using PDF of $Y$.

Comment: Hmm. One point of concern here is that the proposed objective function is trivially maximized by setting $a_1$ and $a_2$ to zero, and $a_0$ to the mode of $\hat{f}_Y$. This would mean that the estimated $a_0$ doesn't depend on $X$, and $a_1$ and $a_2$ don't depend on the data at all.

Comment: @user20160 that makes sense. As a practical solution, I'd try to assign priors to coefficients.